# O que seria WSGI?

Tags: python, aplicação-web

Estava lendo a respeito do termo [WSGI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) para entender um pouco mais o funcionamento de aplicações web em Python, e percebi que alguns microframeworks como o Flask usa esta tecnologia.

Entretanto, eu ainda continuo confuso em relação ao WSGI, parece que não compreendi muito bem a proposta dele ou o que ele é de fato. Eu gostaria que respondessem algumas perguntas a respeito.

## Perguntas

1. O que é WSGI?
2. Qual a relação que ele tem com minha aplicação web?
3. WSGI é apenas para Python?

Comment: Prevejo uma resposta do jsbueno em 5... 4... 3..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. O que é WSGI?

"Web Server Gateway Interface"... é uma camada que fica entre o servidor web e a sua aplicação.

> 2. Qual a relação que ele tem com minha aplicação web?

Você tem que desenvolver a sua aplicação de acordo com a especificação da interface. Funciona assim: Ao invés de desenvolver a sua aplicação fazendo ela conversar usando o protocolo HTTP diretamente com o navegador (abrindo `socket`s e etc) você deixa essa tarefa para o servidor web, e fornece apenas uma função.

O servidor web WSGI vai receber as requisições do navegador e chamar a sua função automaticamente, passando os dados da requisição... E você só tem que escrever a lógica para retornar a resposta.

Se a sua aplicação web seguir a WSGI, poderá ser usada em qualquer servidor web que suporte WSGI também. Além disso existem *middlewares* que são como plugins, podem ser colocados em qualquer aplicação WSGI.

> 3. WSGI é apenas para Python?

Sim, a especificação WSGI pressupõe que você deve escrever uma função em python que será chamada pelo servidor.

Hoje em dia a maioria dos frameworks python, como django, pylons, flask suportam o formato WSGI, de forma que as aplicações desenvolvidas podem ser publicadas em qualquer servidor WSGI.